# Do pharma hacks always redirect to attacker page or can it also be ads on the legit website’s page?

Tags: malware, phishing

I'm trying to understand how a pharma hack works. Let's say someone searches for some illegal drug on google and clicks on a link with a domain name `www.example.com`.

Will that person be redirected to a vulnerable page of `www.example.com` with ads of that illegal drug on it or will he be redirected to the hacker's website? (example: `www.pharmaattack.example`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, **both** scenarios can happen.

When a hacker gets access to your site, he or she can do everything they want, ranging from embedding spammy links to nefarious sites, changing the title of your pages, and even adding new pages.

However, I have lately seen lots of examples of attackers directing to the pharma page, located on the same site domain.

(In this example, a page created by the hacker and placed on `www.example.com/xxxx/illegaldrug~~`)

They also mess up your database.

[This link](https://blog.threatpress.com/pharma-spam-identify-hacked-website/) illustrates the process of pharma spam and prevention very well: